# Why is an image not showing in a div

Tags: html, css

beginner here!
I am following a series of HTML and CSS by Dani Krossing on YouTube, and I followed his series. I reached his video on image in HTML and imported images using div. However for some reason, it's not displaying in my website. I followed the tutorial to a tee but to no avail. Please help me. Here is the HTML code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 60px;
  width: 1000px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: darkred;
}

.img-lightning {
  width: 400;
  height: 229;
  background-image: url(images/lightning.jpg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Front Page</h1>
  <div class="img-lightning"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the image of the website having the error:
[The website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve84p.png)

Comment: Which folder is the image in?

Comment: Typo: You forgot the units on the height and width, so the div has no pixels to display the background on. Use a validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I tested. Things work without the px in Firefox. Maybe a directory call of where ur image sits

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have forgot to mention property unit

```
.img-lightning {
  width: 400px;
  height: 229px;
  background-image: url(images/lightning.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote width and height without units.

update:
width: 400; -> width: 400px;
height: 229; -> height: 229px;

```
.img-lightning {
  width: 400px;
  height: 229px;
  background-image: url(images/lightning.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you get the cracked image? If so - its pulling the data correct but perhaps your link to image is wrong.

Check your directory path especially if your css is in a /css directory.
Your call here background-image: url(images/lightning.jpg); is assuming it is in: /css/images

I keep my directories seperate... (main)/css and (main)/images

If that is the case you may need to go back 1 directory. Add? ../

background-image: url(../images/lightning.jpg);

Also just saw...
width: 400;
height: 229;

Should it be?

width: 400px;
height: 229px;